# What is the difference between =+ and +=

Tags: java

What is the difference between the two notations :

```
encryText =+ text;
```

and

```
encryText += text;
```

*Note : encryText and text are both strings*

Comment: Your code doesn't compile in the first case. You cannot apply a String concat with nothing.

Comment: `encryText =+ text` gives compile time error. Have you try it?

Comment: Please refrain from changing the context of the question completely, after answers have been posted to the original question. If they were supposed to be String, it should be been mentioned in the question from the start and not as an edit, after an answer was posted to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
encryText =+ text;
```

can be interpreted as

```
encryText = +text; // positive(text) assigned to encryText
```

and

```
encryText += text;
```

can be interpreted as

```
encryText = encryText + text; // encryText is added with text and assigned back to encryText
```

`positive(text)` - means a positive integer. You're just explicity specifying the sign here. Usually, the positive integers are specified without the `+` symbol.

`1` - positive number 1 (even without `+` symbol, it means positive integer 1)

`+1` - positive number 1, the `+` symbol is specified explicitly (nothing different than the above, other than explicit `+`)

`-1` - negative number 1, the `-` symbol is required to tell that its a negative integer.

---

**Edit:**

You edited your question and completely changed the context here(which is totally not done). Nevertheless, in case both are strings,

```
encryText += text;
```

can be interpreted as

```
encryText = encryText + text; // String concatenation happens here
```

and

`encryText =+ text;` - would give you a compilation error. You can't use `+` on a string as such. Its not valid operation which can be performed on a String in java.

Comment: What do you mean by positive assigned to `encryText` ?

Comment: _..positive(text) - means a positive integer. You're just explicity specifying the sign here"_ I didn't get you

Comment: but what does a positive string mean ?

Comment: You changed your question. Initially it did not say that both are Strings.

Comment: This is wrong, the term encryText =+ text is a bad compiler value

Comment: @CloudyMarble - The OP changed the question completely. And that's obnoxious.

Comment: Your right, i removed my downvote after your Edit. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
encryText =+ text;
```

Is not valid code, it will cause a compilation error.
See [here](http://ideone.com/GKUX8x)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is =+ Isn't an operator as far as the java spec is concerned (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) . The most java might do is interpret your statement as

`encryText = +text;` (whatever that will do i don't know)

But it's not going to do anything comparable to +=.